# The last record reads twice when reading DBF in Java via jdbf

Tags: java, dbf

**[jdbf](https://github.com/iryndin/jdbf)** is the great utility. Thank for [developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395751/iryndin). But I was found one small issue. 
When I read my dbf, the last record is always occurs twice... Is there a solution?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.ParseException;
import net.iryndin.jdbf.core.DbfRecord;
import net.iryndin.jdbf.reader.DbfReader;

public class JDBFTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        DbfRecord rec = null;
        DbfReader reader = new DbfReader( new File("./src/gds_im.dbf") );
        while( (rec = reader.read()) != null ) {
            rec.setStringCharset( Charset.forName("Cp866") );
            System.out.println( rec.toMap() );
        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of JDBF. 
I have just created an issue at GitHub for this problem:

https://github.com/iryndin/jdbf/issues/3

Will check up and fix this. Please track Github issue about updates.

Comment: The issue is fixed, see commit: https://github.com/iryndin/jdbf/commit/2c5a5df5993a490507d7634a056401ce394653d8